Using jq to replace the value of a JSON field is not working correctly
I have a template JSON file like this:
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "body_t",
        "value": "TEST"
      }
    ],
    "id": "abc123"
  }
]

I need to replace the "value" of the "body_t" (which is set to TEST in the template).
jq '.[].fields[] | select(.name == "body_t") | .value = "'"TEST"'"' template.json

I receive back the following error:
Cannot index string with string "fields"
What am I doing wrong here?

If you want to keep the original structure, I'd use:
map(.fields[] |= (select(.name == "body_t").value |= "Some value"))


[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "body_t",
        "value": "Some value"
      }
    ],
    "id": "abc123"
  }
]


JqPlay Demo

jq 'map(.fields[] |= (select(.name == "body_t").value |= "Some value"))' template.json returns the same error as before.

Did you check the demo link? That works with the provided JSON. There might be something different in you're data. Please edit your question to add that.

Thanks.  You are right.  The issue was that my file was in Windows format with the wrong type of line breaks and that was mucking it up.

What I would do:
$ jq '.[].fields[] | select(.name == "body_t") | .value = "TESTOS"' file
{
  "name": "body_t",
  "value": "TESTOS"
}


It's still returning the same error as before.

Turned out to be a text file line break issue.  Thanks!
